# Google Tag Manager gets ERR_ABORTED 404 in chrome

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have GTM running with some tags that I have had working successfully in many browsers.
It has worked in Chrome before, both incognito and normal. Also in IE11, Firefox ++

But right now I get the following error in my Chrome: 
[image]

While still in Chrome, but using incognito. It loads perfectly fine and displays what i'm expecting on the page:

[image]

We have users complaining about the same behavior. What could possibly cause this? And what could I do to remedy the situation for my users?

I have tried to add &v=1 to the end of the url, just in case it was cached, without any luck.
I have also tried to remove all cookies for this particular page, without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

thats weird. That error usually occurs when you have an unpublished GTM container. Are you sure you have been working with this GTM account before? If not, the other thing that comes to my mind is to check if the owner (if its not you) didn't delete the container. It could have been an accident, for example if the person who initially created the account, gets his email deleted (imagine this person left his job and his work email is disabled), then the GTM account goes automatically to GTM's trash can by default, causing a 404 error as well.

Comment: Yes I know. I have had this error message before when that was the case.. Now it's working for 95% of browsers and chromes, but sometimes it does this. I'm the only one that creates and deletes containers... So... It's very frustrating... Especially since it works in inkognito right now, but not normal chrome..

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks to be caused by an expired GTM preview cookie. Can you try to exit the preview mode in GTM and re-activate it again?

Here is a post with more details about this error: https://analyticshelp.io/blog/fix-google-tag-manager-not-loading-404-error/

Comment: This happened for our users, not just me. The time it happened to me, it might have had this cause, but for our users, I doubt it..

Comment: @Bjørn Sorry to ask but how do you know this happened to your users?

Comment: Support. They call us and describe the problem.

Comment: @Bjørn, what is the impact for your users ? I mean why would they look at their console to see if GTM is aborting ? What is the functional impact for them ?
Don't you have any adblocking extension (even disabled) in your Chrome base profile ? What happens when you open the GTM URL in a new tab ?

Comment: The snippet that is supposed to be added by gtm does not get added, and our users see that it&#39;s not added. They contact us, we tell them to check the console. They do. It shows this message. Adblock was not in use. If I open the url in a new tab it shows a 404. Just like on the page.